# Redirect URLs with #! dynamic content

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, zend-framework2, seo

I had a temporary site made on Wix, and will soon need to move to a new one made in Zend Framework 2. For SEO reasons, not to lose the ranking gained so far, I need to 301 redirect the page URLs of the old site to pages in the new one, the problem is that Wix uses some weird addresses like www.mysite.com/#!about/etc, so the Redirect 301 rule in .htaccess doesn't work as the stuff after the # is not seen as a part of the link. How can I redirect from such URLs without losing their Google juice? Thanks.

Comment: You have to handle `/#!about/etc` in JS

Comment: Won't I lose my SEO results if I don't 301 redirect the full URL?

Comment: There can be no 301 on JS but part after `#` is not even seen on Web server. You will need a combo of JS and server side rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, I found out Wix is using Ajax crawling, which is really unfriendly when you need to move away and redirect your pages, as it uses #! in the URLs.
I also found out that those URLs get parsed by Google as escaped fragments, so I used

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=about/etc$
RewriteRule ^$ /about? [R=301,L]
```

Hope that does the job and redirects my old pages' Google juice to the new ones.

Comment: I think so, but I don't know how to tell.

Comment: If you visit the page with ?_escaped_fragment_=about/etc at the end, does the page get redirected?

Comment: So, from your example, www.mysite.com/?_escaped_fragment_=about/etc  If your redirect is working, it should catch and redirect requests like that I believe.

Answer (score 0):

This code should allow you to transfer the parameters to the final site with a 301.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.tld [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.tld/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: So how to just 301 redirect "/#!about/etc" to "/about" on the same domain? Sorry I still don't understand those .htaccess rules much.

Comment: Can you give me some examples of what redirects you want exactly?

Comment: The current page is "www.mysite.com/#!about/etc" and it has to be redirected to the new page on the same domain "www.mysite.com/about".
There are just a few pages, so I can easily handle them once I know how to do this.

Comment: If I try:  
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^/#!about/etc [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /about$1 [R=301,L]`  
it doesn't work and just stays in the home page. What's wrong?