# PHP Url String Decode

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I have a client that has been using 'wix' for her website and the URLs 
are in the format http://www.website.com/#!about/c15v1

I'm writing a PHP redirect script that uses

```
$requri = getenv ("REQUEST_URI");
```

The problem is that because of the URL /#!
the URI shows up as null

even an extended script which I found elsewhere in stackoverflow

```
$url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].':'.$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
print_r($url);
```

the URL shows up as the root url:80

What I need to do is extract the page name so we can redirect the old site URLs to the correct pages - otherwise her 600 pages will all go to 'index.php' the root url

I was going to use PHP to do this however perhaps this has to be done in the .htaccess file?

Can someone offer ideas? Thank you.

Comment: OK - so how does Wix know what page they're referring to? they must be able to because the fragment identifiers are being seen by Wix somehow. I have to write a redirect script.

Comment: Wix.com - one of the most popular web platforms on the net?
the full URL of her 'about' page is http://www.bodyflows.com/#!about/c15v1 

every page in the Wix platform uses fragment identifiers as you can see.  We're moving her site off of wix but can't figure out how to identify the fragments.  You're saying they are using Ajax or something to write the page?

Comment: We have to tell Google where the 'new' page is - if you do a site:bodyflows.com for example you'll see there are 600 pages all with fragment identifiers in the google index.  Google must be able to read the pages even with the fragment identifiers somehow ON THE SERVER side. How are they doing it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110038/discussion-between-viktor-and-paul-crovella).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect URLs with #! dynamic content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28539043/redirect-urls-with-dynamic-content)